# undefined local variable or method `sign_out_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm beginner in rails application. I have used devise gem to authentication purpose.
when I log in its showing error:
**undefined local variable or method `sign_out_path'**

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what's the output of rake routes?

Comment: do you have routes for devise mentioned in your routes.rb? This particular line => devise_for :users

Comment: u can use something like .. <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be two reasons for this:

1. You have not got the correct routes defined in your routes configuration file
2. You have used a path helper for an existing route but mistakenly used the wrong name

First run rake routes. Have a look through the output and see if you can see any routes beginning with "devise".

If you can see one called "destroy_user_session" then this is actually the name you need to use for your sign out link, and not "sign_out_path". In that case, go to the view where you have put your sign out link and replace the helper with "destroy_user_session_path".