# rails 5 adding menu to dashing-rails layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dashing

What is the best way to be able to add a similar layout to dashing dashboard, like we have in out application. I tried to add the same materalize layout I use throughout my application and it seems to be breaking on each link_to which I have in my main layout.

example of a broken link:

```
undefined local variable or method `edit_user_registration_path'
```

adding routes file portion as an example.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Dashing::Engine, at: Dashing.config.engine_path
  resources :bills
  resources :unit_types, :except => [:show]
end
```

so if I add link_to bills_path it results in error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952066/undefined-local-variable-or-method-sign-out-path#19953957

Comment: Please give us some context and code raising this error. Where exactely do you call `edit_user_registration_path`? Is `edit_user_registration` listed in `rake routes`?

Comment: route added and an example provided.

Comment: The answer is provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46054685/827770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is provided here.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46054685/827770)

all that is needed is a link_to with main_app before the actual route.

```
<%= link_to "About", main_app.about_path %>
```